# Why is tailwindcss working only with my index.html

Tags: html, docker, tailwind-css

I have followed the steps provided in the tailwindcss.com website to get started using nodejs packages.

```
npm install -D tailwindcss
npx tailwindcss init
```

This is my tailwind.config.js file:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./dist/*.{html,php,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'black-dark': '#00000050',
        'dull-white': '#FFFFFFB3',
        'white-light': '#FFFFFF30',
        'white-medium': '#FFFFFF40',
        'neon-blue': '#2FB8FF'
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

And I am running the command: `npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/tail.css --watch`

This is my project structure:

```
├───dist
|   ├───tail.css
|   ├───index.html
|   ├───dashboard.html
├───node_modules
└───src
    ├───input.css
```

The input.css file:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

The tailwindcss styles are applying only to the index.html file but not to the dashboard.html file.
Here is the dashboard.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tail.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="text-3xl bg-blue-400 font-bold font-sans">Hello world</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And I am building this application in a docker container. Here is the docker compose file:

```
version: '3' # docker version
services:
  www:
    image: php:apache
    volumes:
      - "./:/var/www/html" # sync project dir with web container dir
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=db
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSOWRD=1
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - 8001:80
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=db
      - PMA_PORT=3306
```

I know it doesn't have anything to do with docker, but just in case I am adding this.

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong.

###### I ran the  `npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/tail.css --watch` command and used the tail.css file in both my index.html and dashboard.html files, but the styles are applying only to the index.html file but not the dashboard.html file

Comment: Does it not _load_ the stylesheet, when you are on your dashboard page?

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="tail.css">` should probably be something like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/tail.css">`. With the slash.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thank you! It worked when I changed it to `href="./tail.css"` . I have already tried this but it didn't work. Now its working fine.